# Pandas Dataframe Comparison and Floating Point Precision

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to compare two dataframes which should be identical. However due to floating point precision I am being told the values don't match. I have created an example to simulate it below. How can I get the correct result so the final comparison dataframe returns true for both cells?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,97.35000000001]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,97.34999999999]})
print a

   A  
0  100.00  
1   97.35  

print b

   A  
0  100.00  
1   97.35  

print (a == b)

   A  
0  True  
1  False
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK you can use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for this:

```
In [250]:
np.isclose(a,b)

Out[250]:
array([[ True],
       [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

`np.isclose` takes relative tolerance and absolute tolerance. These have default values: `rtol=1e-05`, `atol=1e-08` respectively

Comment: This is perfect, thanks @EdChum. For reference to get a dataframe result as the same type as the original equality check I did:
    `print pd.DataFrame(np.isclose(a,b), columns=a.columns, index=a.index)`
      A  
0  True  
1  True

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas built-in [assert_frame_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html), that automagically performs the numpy isclose() for floating point columns. The advantage is that you can pass an entire dataframe with mixed column types.

For fine tuning see arguments rtol and atol.

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```