# Pandas Dataframe Float Precision

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

I am trying to alter my dataframe with the following line of code:

```
 df = df[df['P'] <= cutoff]
```

However, if for example I set *cutoff* to be 0.1, numbers such as 0.100496 make it through the filter.

My suspicion is that my initial dataframe has entries in scientific notation and float format as well. Could this be affecting the rounding and precision? Is there a potential workaround to this issue.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I am reading from a file. Here is a sample of the total data.

```
2.29E-98
1.81E-42
2.19E-35
3.35E-30
0.0313755
0.0313817
0.03139
0.0313991
0.0314062
0.1003476
0.1003483
0.1003487
0.1003521 
0.100496
```

Comment: What you are suggesting is happening, shouldn't happen.  That means something is wrong.  Likely, it is your data.  You should post an example that produces the result you claim you're getting.

Comment: How are you creating the df? Are you reading from a file? I ran the code here using the same example you mentioned and it worked fine.

Comment: I have just made some edits to my question. Sorry for not having more background information!

Comment: What you describe is almost certainly _not_ what's happening; there's something else at work here that you're not showing us. If you can post a complete executable example that demonstrates the behaviour you're seeing, then we can help. Otherwise, we're left guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point comparison isn't perfect. For example

```
>>> 0.10000000000000000000000000000000000001 <= 0.1
True
```

Have a look at [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html). It allows you to compare floats and set a tolerance for the comparison.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549193/pandas-dataframe-comparison-and-floating-point-precision)

Comment: This is not the case I believe. I ran the code here with the same numbers he mentioned and it worked. Must be something else

Comment: Another option is to change the datatype. You could have a look at the decimal module. It allows you to save floats as tuples of integers. But the comparison would take longer I think.

Comment: I believe it is the something to do with the dataframe applying the same "significant digits" (3) as the first entry on the list in my question, and thus rounding numbers greater than 0.1 down to 0.1. If anyone has any insight into this, help would be greatly appreciated.