# Why can't i filter a column by a float like i would an integer in python?

Tags: python

For example:

```
df[df['nums']==23].head() #gives what its supposed to, but 
df[df['nums']==35.0454545455].head() #gives a blank df and that value exists in the column.
```

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549193/pandas-dataframe-comparison-and-floating-point-precision?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You are probably confused by numerical precision / display. [mre]

Comment: See also: https://stackoveflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken . Comparing `float`s for equality does not work like you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float value is more specific than the filter you are providing.

You could [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) your float value and compare or `>=` some value would work. A precise float unless precise to the last decimal will not work.